# What should be the file path I use when instantiating a URL for a java URLClassLoader?

Tags: java, filepath, urlclassloader

I'm attempting to use a URLClassLoader am having some trouble.
I'm exclusively running into a ClassNotFoundException at runtime and I'm wondering if the issue is my file path I'm using for the jar file I'm attempting to load in.

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/urlclassloader/java-net-urlclassloader-example-2/) exactly and I'm assuming it works so the only error must be the file path I'm using.

The file path of the jar file on my pc is:

```
C:\xxxx\xxxx\IdeaProjects\TesterforURL\src\com\jcg
```

The line of code I'm using to find it is:

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file://C:/xxx/xxxx//IdeaProjects/TesterforURL/src/com/jcg/classloader.jar")};
```

This is the code within the jar file:

```
package com.jcg;


public class Bean {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from loaded Bean class !!!");
    }

}
```

and this is the full code in my project:

```
package com.jcg;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.net.URL;

import java.net.URLClassLoader;



public class URLClassLoaderTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Getting the jar URL which contains target class
        URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file://C:/xxxx/xxxx//IdeaProjects/TesterforURL/src/com/jcg/classloader.jar")};

        // Create a new URLClassLoader
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls); 

        // Load the target class
        Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.jcg.Bean");

        // Create a new instance from the loaded class
        Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
        Object beanObj = constructor.newInstance();

        // Getting a method from the loaded class and invoke it
        Method method = beanClass.getMethod("sayHello");
        method.invoke(beanObj);

    }

}
```

Is the issue my filepath or is it some other problem with the code?

Thanks in advance and apologies if this is formatted or summarized incorrectly, this is my first question :)

Comment: I don't do Windows.  Are those doubled up forward slashes in your path ok?  The tutorial uses backslashes.  I assume forward slashes work too.  However, in the tutorial, the slashes are never doubled up (it looks like they are, but that's just backslash escaping).

Comment: Is the JAR file really there? On this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I've sorted it, it had to be in the format

file:C:\xxx\URLUsingThingy\src\com\jcg\examples\URLExample.jar

Comment: I'm sure you can use forward slashes, but not two of them on Windows.